# why does python's array uses 2 bytes for unsigned ints, whereas C expects 4 bytes in general?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, space-efficiency

I need to store a large number of unsigned integers. Looking at
https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html, I wonder why python's array uses 2 bytes for unsigned ints whereas the C language expects 4 bytes in general?

Comment: ".. whereas the C language expects 4 bytes in general ..": no. The implementation of `int`  in C has shifted over the decades. The proper C name for your 2-byte value is `short`, and a 4-byte integer is a `long`, and their ranges are defined in the C standards.

Comment: @usr2564301 All integer types in C are specified only using *minimum* bit-widths. It's guaranteed that `long` is *at least* 32 bits, but it could also be 64 bits (or more, but not bigger than `long long`).

Comment: Of course – and so does that table for Python (that column header also says "minimum").